# Remove Menu Item in Maya using Python

Tags: python, maya, mel

How can I remove the menu item from the main window using Python? I have it working using MEL but I need it in Python as well.

The part that isn't working is the `find menu if exists and delete`. I can't seem to find the equivalent in Python.

**Python** (not working)

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

if(???)
{
    #cmds.deleteUI('JokerMartini', menu=True )
}

cmds.menu(label='JokerMartini', tearOff=True, p='MayaWindow')
cmds.menuItem(label='Action 1', c= 'something.run()')
cmds.menuItem(divider=True)
cmds.menuItem(label='Action 2', c= 'something.run()')
```

**Mel** (working)

```
if(`menu -exists JokerMartini`)
{
    deleteUI JokerMartini;
}
global string $gMainWindow;
setParent $gMainWindow;
menu -label "JokerMartini" -to true -aob true JokerMartini;    
menuItem -label "Action 1" -command "something";
menuItem -label "Rename..." -command "something";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an approach for main menu item creation:

```
import maya.cmds as mc

menuJM = "JM"
labelMenu = "JokerMartini"

mc.menu(menuJM, l=labelMenu, to=1, p='MayaWindow')
mc.menuItem(l='Action 1', c='something.run()')
mc.menuItem(d=True)
mc.menuItem(l='Action 2', c='something.run()')
```

And for deletion you should use this approach:

```
if mc.menu(menuJM, l=labelMenu, p='MayaWindow') != 0:
    mc.deleteUI(mc.menu(menuJM, l=labelMenu, e=1, dai=1))
    mc.deleteUI(menuJM)     

mc.refresh()
```

[image]

Comment: why are there 2 calls to mc.deleteUI? and what does dai = 1 and vis = 1 mean?

Comment: @Jitesh, `dai` = deleteAllItems and `vis` is deprecated now. Try one of calls, and then both of them and you'll see why.

Comment: in the latest version of maya, deleteAllItems is not needed anymore. and neither it seems refresh afterwards.
simply run this:
`maya.cmds.deleteUI(menu_name, menu=True)`