# Maya – Custom menu is not showing on menu bar

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to build a custom menu in maya.

google groups has this code and it shows that it works but when i try it does not show in menu bar for me. I have tried for hours. What else is required for it to show in menu.
IOW why does it not show in maya menu bar.

https://groups.google.com/g/python_inside_maya/c/XqM7Rkm2kOE

```
import pymel.core as pm

# Name of the global variable for the Maya window
MainMayaWindow = pm.language.melGlobals['gMainWindow'] 

# Build a menu and parent underthe Maya Window
customMenu = pm.menu('Custom Menu', parent=MainMayaWindow)
# Build a menu item and parent under the 'customMenu'
pm.menuItem(label="menu item 'hihi'", command="print 'hihi'", parent=customMenu)
```

edit :
when querying menus it does show it in the list

```
maya_main_window = mel.eval("$tmpVar = $gMainWindow")

menus = cmds.window(maya_main_window, query=True, menuArray=True)
for menu in menus:
    print menu
```

Comment: The posts in that link are nearly 7 years old, a ton could have changed since then. I suggest finding something up-to-date and see if that helps.

Comment: @RandomDavis, I mean every thing i tried from google search does not show on menu bar. Querying all menus in script editor however has this custom menu ( see above edit )

Comment: You need to parent the menu to the menuBar, not the window. So get the menuBar of MainMayaWindow. and use that as parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It works

I'm using Maya 2020 running on macOS Monterey. Your code works fine. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

```
import pymel.core as pm

MainMayaWindow = pm.language.melGlobals['gMainWindow']
customMenu = pm.menu('Custom Menu', parent=MainMayaWindow)
pm.menuItem(l="menu item 'hihi'", command="print 'hihi'", parent=customMenu)
```

---

### If it doesn't work

If you can't create that menu, the problem is, your module might be corrupted. I think the best two things you can do about it – to ***reinstall*** it, or just use [maya.cmds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44142119/remove-menu-item-in-maya-using-python/44145715#44145715) instead of `PyMel` or `OpenMaya`.

The main reason not to use PyMel – because it's too slow. The main reason not to use OpenMaya – because there's so much boiler plate code. Watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tF1Kbamxzw8) to find out what cons and pros PyMel module has.

Comment: Thank you @Andy Jazz. Not so apparent but the window has been present somewhere behind the workspace option.